# Disable user interaction form MapView in react-native

Tags: react-native

How do I turn of user interaction for an element in React native, similar to IOS, MapView in this case.

```
userInteraction = false
```

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Edit:** [MapView has been removed for React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/wiki/Breaking-Changes#ios-remove-mapview-48f30e---mkonicek), you can find the new docs over at [react-community/react-native-maps/](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/). Thanks @Siraj for pointing this out!

You can use the differents props `MapView` has to disable interaction:

[`pitchEnabled`](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md)

[`rotateEnabled`](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md)

[`scrollEnabled`](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md)

[`zoomEnabled`](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md)

If you feel it's not enough, feel free to submit a PR to React native to implement `userInteraction` as a prop directly.

Comment: Please update your answer, it contains some broken links.

Comment: zoomTapEnabled is added

Comment: pitchEnabled={false}  rotateEnabled={false} scrollEnabled={false}  zoomEnabled={false} worked for me thanks ✌